# check if sms was sent in android?

Tags: android, sms

I want to check if the message was delivered or not. 
if message was not delivered due to cellular signal problem i would make a toast that says "No simcard signal try again"

This is my code in MainActivity.java

```
public void sendSMSMessage(String to, String message) {
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(to, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks. Adios

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(smsSentReceiver);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```